# RigidBody2D velocity, problem with the movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity

I'm trying to move an object up with RigidBody2D velocity, but the code does not work.

```
    SantaRb.velocity = new Vector3(0f, rocketFlyBoost, 0f);

    Vector3 mPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, transform.position.y));
    transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mPosition, moveSpeed);
    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
    difference.Normalize();
    float rotation_z = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotation_z -90f);
```

If I comment all the rows outside the first one, the object moves ok. What I'm wrong with, thanks a lot!

Comment: what does `does not work` mean exactly? Could you add a bit more details around your codeblock? Where is it called?

Comment: is called in Update....so the object moves left and right, just do not apply velocity on the y axis, rather try to go up but resets its position on each frame

Comment: I think the problem is this one: transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mPosition, moveSpeed);

Comment: and if I comment this row, it works perfectly, only that the object no longer changes its x position

Comment: hmmm .... goes if you increase the variable rocketFlyBoost

Comment: when using RigidBodies you should never use `transform.position` instead rather try [`Rigidbody.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) in [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html). The same also for the rotation use [`RigidBody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html). Is there a special reason why you are using `Vector2.Lerp` and not `Vector3.Lerp`?

Comment: and you sure you want `transform.position.y` and not maybe `transform.position.z` in `ScreenToWorldPoint`?

Comment: I want to make a game like this: https://armorgames.com/play/12712/rocket-santa. You better understand if you will open it, and you will understand what I want to do. Thanks a lot

Comment: Because the game is 2D, I do not need the z-axis, that's why I used Vector2

Comment: Then why do you use a `RigidBody` instead of a `RigidBody2D`? And why `new Vector3(0f, rocketFlyBoost, 0f);`?

Comment: Where? .... I do not use Rigidbody....
SantaRb = GetComponent<RigidBody2D>(); 
I use RigidBody2D

Comment: `new Vector3(0f, rocketFlyBoost, 0f);` , because it has to move only on the y-axis. Here also I could use Vector2, but it's not a problem if I use Vector3

Comment: Is your camera in perspective mode or orthographic?